# Getting photo URL of facebook's friends' albums

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want get the permanent URL of a facebook User's friend's album's photos (all of the photos in an album named 'Profile Photos').

Does facebook api have some methods to get it ? I DONT want to download the files myself, only the url that usually start like this: 
https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net.

If facebook does not support it natively, is there a way to achieve this using some other method ?

**My main task is to get around 20 profile photos(URLs of the photos) of each of my service's  user's friends**

Comment: Get all your friends to access your app and grant the app user_photos and you can access them

Comment: @WizKid That would only work when using each friend's Access Token, not from the specific user's Access Token, because all `friends_*` permissions have been removed. It's possible to get the `/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture` though IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your friends photos, because all `friends_*` permissions have been removed with Graph API v2.0.

You can only get the profile pictures of each friend which is using you app via

```
/me/friends?fields=id,name,picutre
```

for example.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Quotes

> - The /me/friends endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app.
> - All friends_* permissions have been removed